# License-holder editing application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, wpf, mvvm, databinding

I am building a WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) application. And I'm trying to use the MVVM (Model–View–ViewModel) design pattern. It's fascinating and rewarding, even though it seems overly complex at times. I am new to programming, and I've only really dabbled in WinForms (Windows Forms) before.

I've been through so many changes and adaptations, by experimenting and trying to implement solutions, that I've sort of lost grip of everything I feel.

### Files

**ViewModels**:
`BaseViewModel.cs`
`MainViewModel.cs`
`AddViewModel.cs`

**Models**:
`ConnectionString.cs`
`LicenseHolder.cs`
`UserInfo.cs`

**Views**:
`HomeWindow.xaml`
`LicenseHolderProfileWindow.xaml`
`LicenseHoldersWindow.xaml`
`LoginScreenWindow.xaml`
`NewLicenseHolderWindow.xaml`

### Application Flow

The `LoginScreen` is the first window to open, which directs you to the `HomeWindow` when you log in.

The `HomeWindow` is basically an assortment of buttons leading to different parts of the application.
Currently only one part is under development at the moment, `LicenseHoldersWindow`.

The `LicenseHoldersWindow` contains a `DataGrid`; which is populated by a SQL server table, bound to an `ObservableCollection`.

### Concerns

The `ObservableCollection` is where the tomfoolery begins.
At the moment I just want to do a few simple thing.
I could easily get things working with WinForms, howeer WPF is making things more challenging.

1. I have the `DataGrid` automatically get the data from the server; without having to press any buttons.
2. I am able to delete rows by clicking a button.
3. I currently add rows, by:

   - clicking a button,
   - opening a new window (`NewLicenseHolderWindow`),
   - filling out `TextBoxes` and clicking a save button (window closes), and
   - closing and re-opening the window (`LicensHoldersWindow`) (clunky way of doing things!)

I am also very interested in streamlining my application.
I want it to fully adhere to the MVVM design pattern.
I want it to be slim, not bulky, I want it to be as *petite* as it possibly can be.
I feel like I am using far to much code-lines, and too many `.cs` files.
Is it possible to just use one `ViewModel`?
My `ConnectionString` and some arbitrary code to drag the entered `UserName` with me to correctly label the logout tag, which is the users e-mail address.
I feel it's not done properly.
Also, `LoginScreen.xaml` is placed in a the view, as you see, and that is not in line with MVVM principles.

### Code

#### Models

`ConnectionString.cs` - just my connection string.

`LicenseHolder.cs` - my holder class, the getters/setters for the `DataGrid` columns.

```
namespace Ridel.Hub.Model {

    public class LicenseHolder {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Foretaksnavn { get; set; }
        public string Foretaksnummer { get; set; }
        public string Adresse { get; set; }
        public int Postnummer { get; set; }
        public string Poststed { get; set; }
        public string BIC { get; set; }
        public string IBAN { get; set; }
        public string Kontakt { get; set; }
        public string Epost { get; set; }
        public string Tlf { get; set; }
        public string Kontonummer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`UserInfo.cs` - simple class to bring with me the e-mail address of the logged in user to fill a label used as a 'Log out'-button.

```
namespace Ridel.Hub {

    public class UserInfo {

        private const string userNameString = "";

        public static string UserName { get; set; } = userNameString;
    }
}
```

#### ViewModels

`MainViewModel`

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
using Ridel.Hub.Model;

namespace Ridel.Hub.ViewModel {

    public class MainViewModel : AddViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged {

        public MainViewModel() {

            FillDataGridLicenseHolders();
        }

        // This method triggers when the user clicks the log out button (which is their e-mail address)
        public static void CloseAllWindowsExceptLoginScreen() {

            Application.Current.Windows
                .Cast<Window>()
                .Where(w => w is not LoginScreenWindow)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(w => w.Close());

            MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel();
            LoginScreenWindow loginScreen = new LoginScreenWindow(viewModel);
            loginScreen.Show();
        }

        public void FillDataGridLicenseHolders() {

            try {

                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new(ConnectionString.connectionString))
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new("select * from tblLicenseHolder", sqlCon))
                using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDaAd = new(sqlCmd))
                using (DataSet ds = new()) {

                    sqlCon.Open();
                    sqlDaAd.Fill(ds, "tblLicenseHolder");

                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {

                        // Adding the rows in the DataGrid to the ObservableCollection
                        LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder {

                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()),
                            Foretaksnavn = dr[1].ToString(),
                            Foretaksnummer = dr[2].ToString(),
                            Adresse = dr[3].ToString(),
                            Postnummer = (int)dr[4],
                            Poststed = dr[5].ToString(),
                            BIC = dr[6].ToString(),
                            IBAN = dr[7].ToString(),
                            Kontakt = dr[8].ToString(),
                            Epost = dr[9].ToString(),
                            Tlf = dr[10].ToString(),
                            Kontonummer = dr[11].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }

        private static bool RemoveFromDB(LicenseHolder myLicenseHolder) {

            string sqlString = $"Delete from tblLicenseHolder where ID = '{myLicenseHolder.ID}'";

            if (MessageBox.Show("Er du sikker på at du ønsker å slette valgt løyvehaver?", "Slett løyvehaver", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes) {

                try {

                    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new(ConnectionString.connectionString))
                    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new(sqlString, sqlCon)) {

                        sqlCon.Open();
                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        return true;
                    }

                }
                catch {

                    return false;
                }

            } else {

                return false;
            }
        }

        private void RemoveLicenseHolderExecute(LicenseHolder myLicenseHolder) {

            bool result = RemoveFromDB(myLicenseHolder);
            if (result)
                LicenseHolders.Remove(myLicenseHolder);
        }

        private RelayCommand<LicenseHolder> _removeLicenseHoldersCommand;

        public RelayCommand<LicenseHolder> RemoveLicenseHoldersCommand => _removeLicenseHoldersCommand
            ??= new RelayCommand<LicenseHolder>(RemoveLicenseHolderExecute, RemoveLicenseHolderCanExecute);

        private bool RemoveLicenseHolderCanExecute(LicenseHolder myLicenseHolder) {

            return LicenseHolders.Contains(myLicenseHolder);
        }   
    }
}
```

`AddViewModel` - this is newly added, based on some feed-back I got, and it was at this point I felt things really got out of hand

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
using Ridel.Hub.Model;

namespace Ridel.Hub.ViewModel {

    public class AddViewModel : BaseViewModel {

        public ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder> LicenseHolders { get; set; }

        public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; private set; }

        public AddViewModel() {

            RefreshCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ExecuteRefreshCommand);
            LicenseHolders = new ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder>();
        }

        private string _foretaksnavn;
        public string Foretaksnavn {

            get { return _foretaksnavn; }
            set { SetValue(ref _foretaksnavn, value); }
        }

        private string _foretaksnummer;
        public string Foretaksnummer {

            get { return _foretaksnummer; }
            set { SetValue(ref _foretaksnummer, value); }
        }

        private string _adresse;
        public string Adresse {

            get { return _adresse; }
            set { SetValue(ref _adresse, value); }
        }

        private int _postnummer;
        public int Postnummer {

            get { return _postnummer; }
            set { SetValue(ref _postnummer, value); }
        }

        private string _poststed;
        public string Poststed {

            get { return _poststed; }
            set { SetValue(ref _poststed, value); }
        }

        private string _bic;
        public string BIC {

            get { return _bic; }
            set { SetValue(ref _bic, value); }
        }

        private string _iban;
        public string IBAN {

            get { return _iban; }
            set { SetValue(ref _iban, value); }
        }

        private string _kontakt;
        public string Kontakt {

            get { return _kontakt; }
            set { SetValue(ref _kontakt, value); }
        }

        private string _epost;
        public string Epost {

            get { return _epost; }
            set { SetValue(ref _epost, value); }
        }

        private string _tlf;
        public string Tlf {

            get { return _tlf; }
            set { SetValue(ref _tlf, value); }
        }

        private string _kontonummer;
        public string Kontonummer {

            get { return _kontonummer; }
            set { SetValue(ref _kontonummer, value); }
        }

        private void ExecuteRefreshCommand() {

            string sqlString = "insert into tblLicenseHolder (Foretaksnavn, Foretaksnummer, Adresse, Postnummer, Poststed, BIC, IBAN, Kontakt, Epost, Tlf, Kontonummer) " +
                "values (@Foretaksnavn, @Foretaksnummer, @Adresse, @Postnummer, @Poststed, @BIC, @IBAN, @Kontakt, @Epost, @Tlf, @Kontonummer)";

            if (Foretaksnavn == null || Foretaksnummer == null || Adresse == null 
                || Postnummer == 0 || Poststed == null || BIC == null || IBAN == null 
                || Kontakt == null || Epost == null || Tlf == null || Kontonummer == null) {

                MessageBox.Show("Fyll ut alle feltene.");

            } else {

                LicenseHolders = new ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder>();
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Foretaksnavn = "Foretaksnavn" });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Foretaksnummer = "Foretaksnummer" });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Adresse = "Adresse" });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Postnummer = Postnummer });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Poststed = "Poststed" });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { BIC = "BIC" });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { IBAN = "IBAN" });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Kontakt = "Kontakt" });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Epost = "Epost" });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Tlf = "Tlf" });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Kontonummer = "Kontonummer" });

                try {

                    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new(ConnectionString.connectionString))
                    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new(sqlString, sqlCon)) {

                        sqlCon.Open();
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foretaksnavn", Foretaksnavn.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foretaksnummer", Foretaksnummer.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adresse", Adresse.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postnummer", Convert.ToInt32(Postnummer.ToString()));
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Poststed", Poststed.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BIC", BIC.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IBAN", IBAN.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kontakt", Kontakt.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Epost", Epost.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tlf", Tlf.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kontonummer", Kontonummer.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Ny løyvehaver lagret.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am especially uncertain about how I've structured the `ExecuteRefreshCommand()`-method.
The addition to the server is no problem, but adding to the `ObservableCollection` is clunky, as I have to re-open the window. Hopefully, there is a way to simplify and compact those two tasks into one: add to server & update `ObservableCollection`. Also, the getters/setters strings seems redundant, can't I get and set what I need using the `LicenseHolder.cs` `model class`?

`BaseViewModel`

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Ridel.Hub.ViewModel {

    public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {

            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) {

                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        protected bool SetValue<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {

            if (Equals(storage, value)) return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Views

I will omit the Windows which are irrelevant (at least to my understanding).
I am only posting the code-behind and the XAML from `LicenseHoldersWindow`, `NewLicenseHolderWindow` and `LicenseHolderProfileWindow`. I'll trim away some of the XAML to make it somewhat readable.

`LicenseHoldersWindow`

```
<Window
    x:Class="Ridel.Hub.LicenseHoldersWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ridel.Hub"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Ridel.Hub.ViewModel" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:MainViewModel}"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Canvas Margin="10,10,10,10">

        <Button
            x:Name="btnLogOut"
            Click="btnLogOut_Click"
            Content="LoggedInUser"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonWithOnlyText}" />

        <Button
            x:Name="btnProfile"
            Background="#48bb88"
            Content="Open profile"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonWithRoundCornersGreen}"
            Visibility="Visible" Click="btnProfile_Click" />

        <Button
            x:Name="btnNew"     
            Click="btnNew_Click"
            Content="New licenseholder"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonWithRoundCornersGreen}" />

        <Button
            x:Name="btnDelete"
            Command="{Binding RemoveLicenseHoldersCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=dgLicenseHolder}"
            Content="Delete licenseholder"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonWithRoundCornersGreen}" />

        <DataGrid
            x:Name="dgLicenseHolder"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            SelectionChanged="dgLicenseHolder_SelectionChanged"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LicenseHolders}"
            SelectionMode="Single">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"
                    Header="ID"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="310"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Foretaksnavn}"
                    Header="Foretaksnavn"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Visible" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Foretaksnummer}"
                    Header="Foretaksnummer"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Adresse}"
                    Header="Adresse"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Postnummer}"
                    Header="Postnummer"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Poststed}"
                    Header="Poststed"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Visible" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Path=BIC}"
                    Header="BIC"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Path=IBAN}"
                    Header="IBAN"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Kontakt}"
                    Header="Kontakt"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Epost}"
                    Header="Epost"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Tlf}"
                    Header="Tlf"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Kontonummer}"
                    Header="Kontonummer"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Ridel.Hub.ViewModel;

namespace Ridel.Hub {

    public partial class LicenseHoldersWindow : Window {

        public LicenseHoldersWindow(MainViewModel viewModel) {

            InitializeComponent();
            btnLogOut.Content = UserInfo.UserName;
            DataContext = viewModel;
        }

        private void btnLogOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            if (MessageBox.Show("Er du sikker på at du ønsker å logge ut?", "Logg ut", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes) {

                MainViewModel.CloseAllWindowsExceptLoginScreen();
            }
        }

        private void dgLicenseHolder_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {

            btnProfile.IsEnabled = true;
            btnDelete.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        private void btnNew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            NewLicenseHolderWindow nlhw = new NewLicenseHolderWindow();
            nlhw.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void btnProfile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            if (this.dgLicenseHolder.SelectedItems.Count == 1) {

                LicenseHolderProfileWindow lpw = new LicenseHolderProfileWindow(null) { Owner = this, DataContext = dgLicenseHolder.SelectedItem };
                lpw.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`NewLicenseHolderWindow`

```
<Window
    x:Class="Ridel.Hub.NewLicenseHolderWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Ridel.Hub.ViewModel" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:AddViewModel}"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Canvas Margin="10,10,42,10">
        <Button
            Name="btnLogOut"
            Click="btnLogOut_Click"
            Content="LoggedInUser"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonWithOnlyText}" />
   
        <TextBox
            Name="txtKontakt"
            Text="{Binding Path=Kontakt}"/>
        <TextBox
            Name="txtTlf"
            Text="{Binding Path=Tlf}"/>
        <TextBox
            Name="txtEpost"
            Text="{Binding Path=Epost}"/>
        <TextBox
            Name="txtForetaksnavn"
            Text="{Binding Path=Foretaksnavn}" />
        <TextBox
            Name="txtForetaksnr"
            Text="{Binding Path=Foretaksnummer}"/>
        <TextBox
            Name="txtAdresse"
            Text="{Binding Path=Adresse}"/>
        <TextBox
            Name="txtPoststed"
            Text="{Binding Path=Poststed}"/>
        <TextBox
            Name="txtPostnummer"
            Text="{Binding Path=Postnummer}"/>
        <TextBox
            Name="txtBIC"
            Text="{Binding Path=BIC}"/>
        <TextBox
            Name="txtIBAN"
            Text="{Binding Path=IBAN}"/>
        <TextBox
            Name="txtKontonr"
            Text="{Binding Path=Kontonummer}"/>

        <Button
            Name="btnSave"
            Command="{Binding Path=RefreshCommand}"
            Content="Save"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonWithRoundCornersGreen}">
        </Button>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using Ridel.Hub.ViewModel;

namespace Ridel.Hub {

    public partial class NewLicenseHolderWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public NewLicenseHolderWindow() {

            InitializeComponent();
            btnLogOut.Content = UserInfo.UserName;
        }

        private void btnLogOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            if (MessageBox.Show("Er du sikker på at du ønsker å logge ut?", "Logg ut", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes) {

                MainViewModel.CloseAllWindowsExceptLoginScreen();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`LicenseHolderProfileWindow`

```
<Window
    x:Class="Ridel.Hub.LicenseHolderProfileWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Ridel.Hub.ViewModel" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:AddViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Canvas Margin="10,10,42,10">
        <Button
            Name="btnLogOut"
            Click="btnLogOut_Click"
            Content="LoggedInUser"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonWithOnlyText}" />

        <TextBox
            Name="txtKontakt"
            Text="{Binding Kontakt, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Kontakt}" />
        <TextBox
            Name="txtTlf"
            Text="{Binding Tlf, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Tlf}" />
        <TextBox
            Name="txtEpost"
            Text="{Binding Epost, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Epost}" />
        <TextBox
            Name="txtForetaksnavn"
            Text="{Binding Foretaksnavn, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Foretaksnavn}" />
        <TextBox
            Name="txtForetaksnr"
            Text="{Binding Foretaksnummer, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Foretaksnummer}" />
        <TextBox
            Name="txtAdresse"
            Text="{Binding Adresse, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Adresse}" />
        <TextBox
            Name="txtPoststed"
            Text="{Binding Poststed, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Poststed}" />
        <TextBox
            Name="txtPostnummer"  
            Text="{Binding Postnummer, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Postnummer}" />
        <TextBox
            Name="txtBIC"
            Text="{Binding BIC, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=BIC}" />
        <TextBox
            Name="txtIBAN"
              Text="{Binding IBAN, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=IBAN}" />
        <TextBox
            Name="txtKontonr"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="{Binding Kontonummer, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Kontonummer}" />

        <Button
            Name="btnLagre"           
            Click="btnLagre_Click"
            Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
            Content="Lagre"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonWithRoundCornersGreen}" />
     </Canvas>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using Ridel.Hub.ViewModel;

namespace Ridel.Hub {

    public partial class LicenseHolderProfileWindow : Window {

        public LicenseHolderProfileWindow(AddViewModel viewModel) {

            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = viewModel;
        }

        private void btnLogOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            if (MessageBox.Show("Er du sikker på at du ønsker å logge ut?", "Logg ut", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes) {

                MainViewModel.CloseAllWindowsExceptLoginScreen();
            }
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            btnAllowEdit.IsEnabled = true;
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't received any pointers, please let me know if I am being unclear in the presentation of my project. Any perspective on improvement will still be very much appreciated.